# Cleanest way to add a field in an Hibernate entity to indicate with a boolean if this entity is referenced in another table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity

I've a database with a classic FK between 2 tabkes.
A table A which is refenced by a FK in table B.

I'm making an entity for A and I would like it to have a boolean attribut indicating if it's referenced by at least 1 B.

Is it possible to do that so I don't have to add a List and check everytime if it's empty or not, even though I don't care about the B at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the hibernate specific, non-JPA compliant @Formula annotation.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-property

```
@Formula("select count(*) from table_b where a_id = id")
private int countOfB;

public boolean hasB(){
    return countOfB > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already, but I think i'm sol since I use JPA transaction, it won't take into account hibernate annotation ? Whenever I add @Formula, I get "Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression"

Comment: As Hibernate is your JPA provider you can use HIbernate specific annotations as you wish.  The problem is in the SQL. I Have slightly updated the answer - try that.

Comment: No dice:     @Formula("count (*) from SQL_TABLEB_name B where B.A_ID = id"). Doesn't even work when I replaced id by a hardcoded value.

Comment: Post the full SQL you are  applying to the Formula plus the stack trace.

Comment: Just tested and @Formula works fine if I'm just working on another attribut like @Formula(id + 2). As for the SQL it's from a select on higher level entity with a fetch on the collection containing A. Can't really post it here.Added the stack in the original message

Comment: There is something wrong with your SQL and if you can't post it  then I can't help you any further.

Comment: Thanks, got it working @Formula(value = "(select count  (TABLE_B.ID) from TABLE_B where TABLE_B.A_ID = id)")
 
Had to put the select keyword since I'm working on another table, parenthesis to avoid SQL error and NOT leave a space between count and left parenthesis or it will add an alias to count

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, got it working with :

`@Formula(value = "(select count (TABLE_B.ID) from TABLE_B where TABLE_B.A_ID = id)")`

1) Put the select keyword since I'm working on another table
2) parenthesis around the whole statement to avoid SQL error
3) Do not leave a space between count and left parenthesis or it will add an alias to count and mess the sql up